# Should models be trained using fori_loop?

Tags: jax, flax

When optimizing weights and biases of a model, does it make sense to replace:

```py
for _ in range(epochs):
    w, b = step(w, b)
```

With:

```py
w, b = lax.fori_loop(0, epochs, lambda wb: step(wb[0], wb[1]), (w, b))
```

If I understand correctly, this means that the entire training process can then be a single compiled JAX function (takes in training data, outputs optimized weights and biases).

Is this a standard approach? What are the tradeoffs to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to train your model with `fori_loop`, particularly for simple models. It may be slightly faster, but in general XLA won't fuse operations across different loop steps. It's also not possible to return early within a `fori_loop` when you reach a certain loss threshold (though you could do that with `while_loop` if you wish).

For more complicated models, you often will want to do some sort of I/O at every step (e.g. loading new training data, logging fit parameters, etc.) While this is possible to do within `fori_loop` via `jax.experimental.io_callback`, it is somewhat less convenient than doing it directly from the host within a Python `for` loop, so in general users tend to use `for` loops for their training iterations.